# trouble running sfml 2.0 Cannot Open Shared Object file, no such file or directory

Tags: c++, sfml

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eefTl.png) is an image of what is going on. I feel like it should give all the information needed.

Please help...this is driving me crazy. I am not sure where to go to even learn this stuff...

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable pointing to the folder where shared libraries are located:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /path/to/so
```

In your case path is currebt directory, `.`
Then start your executable

UPD:
If your shell is not bash you might need to use setenv instead of export:

```
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH    .
```

Comment: @lilsheep: What is your shell? if it's not bash you might need to call setenv instead

Comment: I am using terminal if that is what you mean by shell
[here](http://i.imgur.com/iFYOj.png) is a pic

Comment: @lilsheep: The SHELL environment variable will tell you what login shell is running. Try to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH with setenv, I updated my answer

Comment: " setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH = .
No command 'setenv' found, did you mean:
 Command 'netenv' from package 'netenv' (universe)
setenv: command not found
hassan@hks:~/c++$ setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH .
No command 'setenv' found, did you mean:
 Command 'netenv' from package 'netenv' (universe)
setenv: command not found
"